# How do I create mysql db table with floats and created_at (timestamp)

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I'm not able to figure it out :(  I need help creating two tables in a mysql db. This is what I was told I need to do:

> make sure you have an temps table with floats and created_at (timestamp)
>       make sure you have an alerts table with floats for avgtemp1 and avgtemp2, open (boolean, default: true) and created_at (timestamp)

What I did in phpmyadmin:

1. Created a mysql db named temps
2. Created two tables, (temps, alerts)
3. Created two columns (temp1 and temp2) in the temps table
4. Created two columns (avgtemp1 and avgtemp2) in the alerts table

I don't understand how to add created_at (timestamp)?  or what open (boolean, default: true) and created_at (timestamp)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: MySQL has a `TIMESTAMP` data type. It's documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Basically: `CREATE TABLE myTable (temp1 FLOAT, temp2 FLOAT, temp3 TIMESTAMP);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you what you need for the timestamp column and the boolean column. The `open` column is just a flag that can be set to true or false, but it should default to true, in this case 1.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  open boolean default 1
);
```

Note: you only need the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if you want to, otherwise you can remove that and insert a timestamp manually.